# Python requests response is very slow and not equal to cURL

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

It is bizarre activity, I get different response from cURL and Python with the `requests` module. Also, Python is very slow: cURL takes about 6 seconds, but Python is 2 minutes.

My cURL command is:

```
curl -L -s -k --request GET \ 
--url "https://$1/api/maintenance/maintenance/dual_image_config" \ 
--header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \ 
--header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' \ 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ 
--header 'Connection: keep-alive'
```

The cURL response is:

```
{ "state_1": "Active", "state_2": "stand-by", "current_active_image": "Image-1", "id": 1}
```

My Python code is:

```py
import requests, sys
DEFAULT_HEADER = {"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

url = "https://{0}/api/maintenance/maintenance/dual_image_config".format(sys.argv[1])
response = requests.get(url="", data=None, headers=DEFAULT_HEADER , verify=False)
```

Python response `response.text` is:

```
'0121\r\n{ "state_1": "Active", "state_2": "stand-by", "current_active_image": "Image-1", "id": 1}\r\n0\r\n\r\n'
```

It will have 0121\r\n & \r\n0\r\n\r\n in start and begin, I have try to change request header & encoding, but it not work, why it is got different response, and so slow ?

Comment: You are using different headers, with `requests` you are accepting a different encoding and marking the request as a XHR. The server might indeed be answering differently, try using the same headers and update here if you get the same results

Comment: Thanks for response,I have change DEFAULT_HEADER (delete "X-requested-With", and change Accept-Encoding to gzip, deflate, sdch) to

```
{
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
```
but response still slow and have 0121\r\n & \r\n0\r\n\r\n in start and the end

```
response is 

'0121\r\n{ "state_1": "stand-by", "state_2": "Active", "current_active_image": "Image-2", "id": 1 }\r\n0\r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: I have compare with response header too, python will miss Content-Type": "application/json",
"Date": "Thu, 13 Jan 2000 02:07:32 GMT",
"Server": "lighttpd",
"Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",

Does it have influence ??